# Cannot create/edit AVD - 'No CPU/ABI system available for the target' - error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've tried installing system image ARM EABI v7a system image (and all other System images available in SDK manager)

I can't create or edit AVD. but I have Two AVDs already which is working still.
if any details needed I'm happy to provide....
Thanks in adavnce,

Comment: Try different combinations of CPU type and API Level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't find a Solution still , What I did was unZip the ADT and install it all over again